# System.Web.Caching.Cache expires too early or too late bug

Tags: c#, .net

I came across this Microsoft [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4035412/fix-expiration-time-issue-when-you-insert-items-by-using-the-cache-ins) while researching my issue on our application which runs on .NET 4.7.2

It basically says that if you insert into the .NET Cache using this specific Insert signature with the desire expire time, this bug causes the cache to either expire it earlier or later than the set time.

According to this article, if you are on .NET 4.7 then your cache may expire too early or much later than the set time.  This is last updated in July 2019.

However, I do not see any information on which specific build the fix is in, does this mean that it still presents in .NET 4.7.2? And that the fix will be in .NET 4.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation it should be fixed already. The article dates Jul 19, **2017**. I think you are good.

> **Resolution** This issue will be fixed in the next version of the .NET Framework, and will also be available in the next hotfix for the
>   .NET Framework 4.7.

As per comment - Fixed in .NET 4.7.1 - [see the release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/dotnet471-changes.md)

Comment: That's the part I'm not sure, they say "Next Version", I am unsure if that means 4.7.x or 4.8 and later.

Comment: It says next hotfix too, why not just use one of the other overloads?

Comment: found it in .net 4.7.1 release note https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/dotnet471-changes.md